# Three.js : Upgrading to 0.137.5 causes TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mergeBufferGeometries')

Tags: three.js

I am trying to upgrade my Three.js project from 0.126.1 to 0.137.5 however when I now run the project I get the following error.

> Exception has occurred: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'mergeBufferGeometries')

This is caused by the following method however because this did work I am not sure what to change

```
import { BufferGeometryUtils } from "three/examples/jsm/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js";

extractAndMergeOuterMesh(gltf) {
      const geometries = [];
      gltf.traverse((child) => {
        if (child.isMesh && child.name == "polySurface21") {
          geometries.push(child.geometry);
        }
      });
```

Comment: Try import of BufferGeometryUtils this way: `import * as BufferGeometryUtils from "three/examples/jsm/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js";`

Comment: Thanks, it wont let me import it
npm install --save https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js

npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json: https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

Comment: Sorry your comment has updated, I already have that import

Comment: You actually where right, you have solved my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by prisoner849, this was caused due to Three.js changing how it imported BufferGeometryUtils.

The key was the '*"

```
import * as BufferGeometryUtils from "three/examples/jsm/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js";
```